# Transition between Fragments/FragmentsActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So my app launch when it starts a FragmentActivity `TestFActivity`. That FragmentActivity contains a viewpager, which include 3 Fragments `WelcomeFragment`, `ListFragment`, and `TagFragment`.
Now, I want that when I click on an item from ListFragments, it opens a new FragmentActivity `DetailsView`, that will contains a viewpager (which include all of the items from the `ListFragment` and allow to swipe between them).

I have no clue on how to do that, and if this is the good logic to have with fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting an Activity from within a `Fragment` is no different from starting one from another `Activity`, simply construct an `Intent` with the new Activity classname and call `startActivity()`.  Something like:

```
//Fragments aren't a context, so used getActivity() instead
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsView.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

here is a tutorial on how to use the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)